# How to inherit parent site permissions when creating subSite using webservice

Tags: 2007, permissions, web-services, inheritance

Using Sharepoint 2007 webservices from a .Net web application I create a subSite (CreateDWS method).  I was originally hoping that the parent permissions would be inherited but no such luck.

According to the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772546(office.12).aspx, I should be able to add a XML tag like:

Dim strNewUser As String = <UserInfo> _ 
            <item Email='someone@somewhere.com' Name='username'/> _ 
            </UserInfo>

to the Createdws call.  Although I don't get an error it doesn't add the user to the newly created subSite.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there a webservice I can use to set Inherit Parent permissions explicitly?

Failing that, how can I make this happen or add an Active Directory domain group so that folks in that group can Contribute to the site?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post the segment of your code you wrote to add the user?

Comment: Sure.
First I set a Web Reference to http://sharepointServer/sites/CivilCommit/_vti_bin/dws.asmx
Then
Dim dWS As dohreg2simm046.Dws = New dohreg2simm046.Dws
dWS.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password", "Domain")
vRetVal = dWS.CreateDws("NewDws", strNewUser, txtFirstName.Text + "_" + txtLastName.Text, "")
'Where strNewUser is defined above

The site is created but user isn't added.  Altimately I want to add an Active Directory group either inherited from the parent or added through a webservice and granted "Contribute" rights.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can write and call another segment of code as soon as you create a sub site. This code will call the Permissions Web Service **GetPermissionCollection** method and copy the site permission of the parent site. Later you can call the **AddPermissionCollection** method to add the same to the newly created child web site.

more on the permission web service here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/permissions.permissions_methods(v=office.12).aspx

Hope this helps..

Comment: If you wish to take the other way and add a group to your chid site, then call the Users and Groups Web Service *Add Group* method and pass in the AD group information.

More on this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774470(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I'd tried using the Permission webservice earlier without success.  Probably because I don't understand what it's really doing (or for that matter usergroups).

I'd tried using the AddPermission method (which resulted in a soap exception) not the AddPermissionCollection.  I'll try that next.

I'll get back.
N

Comment: I'm getting a soap exception error when I try the following:

vSPSite = "sites/Root/TestSite"
Dim ndPerms As System.Xml.XmlNode
ndPerms = pWS.GetPermissionCollection("sites/Root", "List")
pWS.AddPermissionCollection(vSPSite, "List", ndPerms)

Any idea what I did wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey.. i see you are using *List* as the objectType but you are specifying a site as objectName.

Try this insted:
pWS.AddPermissionCollection(vSPSite, "Web", ndPerms)

Comment: Thanks but I'd tried it both ways.  Might be a permission issue.  How does one go about debugging a soap exception anyway?

Comment: May i know at what point are you getting this exception? is it that on GetPermissionCollection or while AddPermissionCollection